# Creating SVG file and related commands

Tags: command-line, svg

I've working on a problem which involves creating a SVG file. I've written a VM. My own VM program reads in a string of single character "commands" on stdin using the VM getc instruction. Using these commands it then generates a graphics file in SVG format as output.

Below are six examples of input command strings:

RULDX

PRUPRULDX

PRRUPCBEAX

PRUP J R K PRP JJJJJ R KKKKK PRP JJJJJJJJJ R X

PRUP M U N PUP MMMMM U NNNNN PUP MMMMMMMMM U X

PRUP KKKKKKKKKK KKKKKKKKKK NNNNNNNNNN A X

As far as I've read these strings aren't related to SVG coding or atleast I can't find any relation at all.And I need to use these commands to draw some 2d open figure with lines.

To complete another bigger task I must first determine what the commands demonstrated above do.Please help me in this crossing this hurdle. Do tell me if I didn't explain it well. I doubt my explanation because I myself wasn't able to understand! Thanks in advance !! :D

Answer (score 2):

`RULDX` seems to be a square (Right Up Left Down) and a X to terminate the input (eXecute?)

See [logo](http://el.media.mit.edu/logo-foundation/logo/turtle.html) for a similar example how to make such drawings.

Comment: Oh! THat's very brilliant of you! That can be figured out easily! But how about other commands, my friends... Those commands don't exist in LOGO.. Don't you agree? Please do take a closer look before you vote down my friend!!

THere are commands like P,M, N, K, A ,E ,J

Comment: P is possibly toggle pen up/down, but this is all guessing, and this site is not meant for that. So I think your question is off-topic, but I did not vote your question down.

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that sarcastic tone, mate! Really sorry! Need to that task in a hurry!!!